# Use System.Drawing.Color to draw a line in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, drawing

How can I draw a line in XAML using a `System.Drawing.Color`? A solution without a converter would be nice.

XAML:

`<Line
    X1="10" Y1="10"
    X2="20" Y2="10"
    Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="4" />`

Code:

```
System.Drawing.Color Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Comment: Why don´t you use the [System.Windows.Media.Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Because I need a SharpDX.Color/System.Drawing.Color to draw in DirectX

Comment: You can try to use a string property to return "Black" or "Green". There is an implicit converter that converts strings to SolidColorBrush

Comment: Could you tell me how to use that converter in XAML? Would that be possible?

Comment: change the property `Color` that is bound to the line to type `string` and assign it a value like "Green", "Brown" or "BurlyWood". The implicit converter then converts the string representation to a SolidColorBrush when updating the Binding of the Stroke property

Comment: In combination with this post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857760/pass-color-name-as-string-in-sharpdx-color, I can use this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind a [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx) to the [Stroke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.stroke.aspx) property, in particular a [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx), which accepts a color.

However, you need to convert from [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) to [System.Windows.Media.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g. by passing the R, G, and B values to the [FromRgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Wouldn't that come along with using a converter?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve the same with a converter for creating the SolidColorBrush. I think it is mostly a matter of taste where to put such logic, but a converter seems like a good idea in this case.